# SQL replace value of with always random xml code

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following SQL XML in several rows of a table (table is tbldatafeed column in configuration_xml).  All of the `UserName=""` and `Password=""` is different each time for each row and does not repeat so I can not find/replace off of that.  I am trying to write a query that finds all of those and replaces them with Username/Passwords I choose.

```xml
<DataFeed xmlns="http://www.tech.com/datafeed/dfx/2010/04" xmlns:plugin="pluginExtensions" Type="TODO" Guid="TODO" UserAccount="DF_LEAN_PopulateCommentsSubForm" Locale="en-US" DateFormat="" ThousandSeparator="" NegativeSymbol="" DecimalSymbol="" SendingNotifications="false" SendJobStatusNotifications="false" RecipientUserIds="" RecipientGroupIds="" RecipientEmailAddresses="" Name="CI_C11.01_Lean-Lean_Reject Comments_A2A" >
  <Transporter>
    <transporters:ArcherWebServiceTransportActivity xmlns:transporters="clr-namespace:ArcherTech.DataFeed.Activities.Transporters;assembly=ArcherTech.DataFeed" xmlns:out="clr-namespace:ArcherTech.DataFeed;assembly=ArcherTech.DataFeed" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:compModel="clr-namespace:ArcherTech.DataFeed.ComponentModel;assembly=ArcherTech.DataFeed" xmlns:channel="clr-namespace:ArcherTech.DataFeed.Engine.Channel;assembly=ArcherTech.DataFeed" xmlns:engine="clr-namespace:ArcherTech.DataFeed.Engine;assembly=ArcherTech.DataFeed" xmlns:kernel="clr-namespace:ArcherTech.Kernel.Channel;assembly=ArcherTech.Kernel" xmlns="clr-namespace:ArcherTech.DataFeed;assembly=ArcherTech.DataFeed" xmlns:schema="clr-namespace:System.Xml.Schema;assembly=System.Xml" xmlns:xmlLinq="clr-namespace:System.Xml.Linq;assembly=System.Xml" xmlns:domain="clr-namespace:ArcherTech.Common.Domain;assembly=ArcherTech.Common" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" x:Key="transportActivity" SearchType="ReportId" Uri="https://arcs-d" RecordsPerFile="100" ReportID="EC514865-88D5-49CE-A200-7769EC1C2A88" UseWindowsAuth="false" IsWindowsAuthSpecific="false" WindowsAuthUserName="i9XzCczAQ7J2rHwkg6wG9QF8+O9NCYJZP6y5Kzw4be0+cdvUaGu/9+rHuLstU736pnQrRcwmnSIhd6oPKIvnLA==" WindowsAuthPassword="+y0tCAKysxEMSGv1unpHxfg6WjH5XWylgP45P5MLRdQ6+zAdOLSVy7s3KJa3+9j2i83qn8I8K7+1+QBlCJT1E7sLQHWRFOCEdJgXaIr1gWfUEO+7kjuJnZcIEKZJa2wHyqc2Z08J2SKfdCLh7HoLtg==" WindowsAuthDomain="" ProxyName="" ProxyPort="8080" ProxyUsername="" ProxyPassword="" ProxyDomain="" IsProxyActive="False" ProxyOption="None" InstanceName="ARCS-D" TempFileOnSuccessAction="DoNothing" TempFileOnSuccessRenameString="" TempFileOnErrorAction="DoNothing" TempFileOnErrorRenameString="" Transform="{engine:DataFeedBinding Path=Transform}" SessionContext="{engine:DataFeedBinding Path=Session}">
      <transporters:ArcherWebServiceTransportActivity.Credentials>
        <NetworkCredentialWrapper UserName="TeSZmI1SqO0eJ0G2nDVU+glFg/9eZfeMppYQnPfbeg8=" Password="Slt4VHqjkYscWyCwZK40QJ7KOQroG9OTKr+RGt9bQjE=" />
      </transporters:ArcherWebServiceTransportActivity.Credentials>
    </transporters:ArcherWebServiceTransportActivity>
  </Transporter> 
</DataFeed>
```

I need to be able to set a value and replace it with a query

I have written the following

```
select @config_xml=configuration_xml from bldatafeed where datafeed_name = 'REMOVED'
update tbldatafeed set configuration_xml.modify(//*:NetworkCredentialWrapper/@UserName)[1] with "abc" ')
where datafeed_name = 'REMOVED'
```

This does the trick but it only works if I set the "abc" password each time in each area and in some cases I am running this against 50+ rows.

I also tried:

```
Declare @server nvarchar(max) = 'abc'
Declare @config_xml xml
select @config_xml=configuration_xml from bldatafeed where datafeed_name = 'REMOVED'
update tbldatafeed set configuration_xml.modify(//*:NetworkCredentialWrapper/@UserName)[1] with @server ')
where datafeed_name = 'REMOVED'
```

The error from this is that: XQuery [tbldatafeed.configuration_xml.modify()]: Top-level attribute nodes are not supported

What I would like to be able to do is set my variable and utilize that as I will be setting this up for multiple rows and unfortunately this error is making this a very difficult problem to solve.

Thanks for any help, this has kept me confused for a bit.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? XML support varies quite a bit between vendors... Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function [sql:variable()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-extension-functions-sql-variable?view=sql-server-2017) to use a variable in the XQuery expression.

```
declare @T table(X xml);
insert into @T values('<X UserName=""/>');

declare @UserName nvarchar(max) = 'abc'

update @T set
X.modify('replace value of (/X/@UserName)[1] 
           with sql:variable("@UserName")');
```

Comment: This works using sql:variable now to figure out why the same xml path I was using isnt working.  Thank you!